# Finding the domain of this trigonometric function

Tags: functions, trigonometry

how can I find the domain of this function?

```
 f(x) = (xsin(x) + cos(x) / 1 - cos(x)) + (|X| - 2 / x^2 -4)
```

I assume we don't want the dominator to be zero so f(x)1 1 - cos(x) != 0 and x^2 - 4 != 0?
What is the next step

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, please take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and learn the basic rules of the site. Your question may be put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because it seems to be [off-topic](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), i.e. its about mathematics and not Mathematica. If that's not the case, [edit your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to make it explicitly about Mathematica programming. Include a minimum example of the code you are working on and use the correct syntax.

Comment: go to help and look for FunctionDomain